# How to print dynamic contents of array at different positions in HTML5

Tags: javascript, json, html, jsonp

I have to fetch data from the PHP web service in an array and then display it on HTML page using JavaScript. I have used a `for` loop to do so. But it doesn’t render proper output. Due to `innerHTML` the output gets replaced. Please help with your suggestions. Here is my code:

```
function jsondata(data){
    alert("JSONdata");
    var parsedata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    var main_category = parsedata["main Category"];
    for (var i = 0; i <= main_category.length; i++) {
        menu = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(main_category[i]));
        menu_id[i] = menu['mcatid'];
        menu_title[i] = menu['mcattitle'];
        menu_img[i] = menu['mcatimage'];
        pop_array.push(menu_id[i], menu_title[i], menu_img[i]);
        //alert(pop_array);
        for (var i = 0; i < main_category.length; i++) {
            alert("for start");
            var category = document.createElement("li");
            document.getElementById("mylist").appendChild(category);
            //document.getElementById("mylist").innerHTML='<table><tr><td>'+pop_array[i]+'</td></tr></table>';
            document.write(pop_array.join("<br></br>"));
            alert("for end");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't get why `pop_array` was used here but I assume that you are trying to display the `category` info as a `li` tag.

You should set `category.innerHTML` instead of `document.getElementById("mylist").innerHTML`.

```
function jsondata(data){
    var parsedata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    var main_category = parsedata["main Category"];

    for (var i = 0; i < main_category.length; i++) {
        var menu = main_category[i];
        var category = document.createElement("li");
        category.innerHTML = menu['mcattitle'];      // construct your own html here
        document.getElementById("mylist").appendChild(category);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to take 3 things:id,text and image, so i have populated the pop_array. Right now am trying to display text part. I have to display all these things at proper positions. I am able to fetch array elements now, next to find is to separate that id, text and image and display at proper positions.